# How to open Network Connections profiles as admin.Login as administrator

Tags: windows, networking

How can I run this as admin? When I set it on , it disables automatically.
I Login as administrator.

[image: Here is picture]

Comment: Looking at the screenshot in the question there aren't any other connected networks - so nothing to bridge to? Although I'm 99% you'd see an error message indicating that as the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Start command prompt with **elevated** rights, paste **ncpa.cpl** into command line and **run command**.

**Like Below.**

[image]

Screen should pop up then just **right click** and select **properties.**

[image]

Or try this it does exactly the same thing you want to do.

1.Open Network Connections by clicking the **Start button** , and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click **View network connections**.

2.**Hold down** the **Ctrl key** and select each network connection that you want to add to the bridge.

3.**Right-click** one of the selected network connections, and then click Bridge Connections.  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Comment: I try this method, doesnt work. Cant turn on that function.it disables automatically at once

Comment: Could you give a little more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes of course. I want to activate it to share internet from 3G modem with my notebook.

Comment: I updated the method try what's below the picture.

Comment: i use Windows 10 and there is no function  to add to the bridge after View network connections.I try all nothing help, i'll reinstall windows, maybe it will help, nobody help me , i write everywhere, microsoft forum and other places, nobody now the answer of my question :( Thanks for all

Comment: Did you select both connections with Cntl key and then right click on of the connections? I just tried it on my windows 10 Professional and it worked.

Comment: for other connections like wi fi and ethernet i don't need cntrl key or adin mode, all works cool, , but only for this connection admin mode doesn't work :( dont understand why.